# connect SSH to target machine that public key is in custom folder

Tags: ssh

I just connected on a machine in SSH and then moved .ssh folder to .ssh.bak/

Now I am disconnected, I cannot connect anymore to this machine

with -i option, I can specifiy a custom private key to connect, but is it posible to specify a custom public key in target machine in the ssh command?

Comment: No, this is not possible. It has to be configured on the target machine.

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not possible. The location of the public key files has to be configured on the target machine.

You will have to log in with a different method (password authentication, different user, local console) to move the files back where they belong.